# Разбиение проекта С++

Tags: c++

Добрый вечер, возникла проблема при разбиение проекта на несколько файлов. Исходный код работал как надо и проблем не было до тех пор, пока я его не разбил на несколько файлов. После разбиения программа компилируется без ошибок, но выводит какое то не понятное число.

Исходный код:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

 int m, n;
 float **matr, *mas;

 void InputMatr()
 {
cout << "Count row M: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "\nCount colomn N: ";
cin >> n;
    cout << "Input matrix: ";

matr = new float *[m];
for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    matr[i] = new float[n];

for (i=0; i<m; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        cin>>matr[i][j];

mas = new float[n];
}

void Calculations()
{
float min;
int id=0;

for (int i=1; i<m; i+=2)
{
    min = matr[i][0];
    for (int j=1; j<n; j++)
    {
        if (matr[i][j] < min) min = matr[i][j];
    }
    if (min<0){ mas[id]=min;id++; }
}
}

void main(float)
{

    void OutputMas();
clrscr();
InputMatr();
Calculations();
OutputMas();
getch();
}

void OutputMas(void)
{
clrscr();
cout<<"Rezulting massiv "<< " ";
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(mas);i++)
{
cout<<mas[i]<<" ";
}
}
```

А вот код после разбиения на 4 файла:
**lab1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include "lab1.hpp"
#include "lab2.hpp"
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Calculations()
{
float min;
int id=0;

for (int i=1; i<m; i+=2)
{
    min = matr[i][0];
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        if (matr[i][j] < min) min = matr[i][j];
    }
    if (min<0){ mas[id]=min;id++; }
}
}

void main(float)
{

    void OutputMas();
clrscr();
InputMatr(matr, m, n);
Calculations();
OutputMas();
getch();
}

void OutputMas(void)
{
clrscr();
cout<<"Rezulting massiv "<< " ";
for (int i=0; i<sizeof(mas);i++)
{
cout<<mas[i]<<" ";
}
}
```

**lab2.cpp**

```
#include "lab1.hpp"
#include <iostream.h>

void InputMatr(float **matr, int m, int n)
{
cout << "Count row M: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "\nCount colomn N: ";
cin >> n;
    cout << "Input matrix: ";

matr = new float *[m];
for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    matr[i] = new float[n];

for (i=0; i<m; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
        cin>>matr[i][j];

mas = new float[n];
}
```

**lab1.hpp**

```
#if !defined (__LAB1_HPP)
#define __LAB1_HPP
static int m, n;
static float **matr, *mas;
#endif  /* __LAB1_HPP*/
```

**lab2.hpp**

```
 extern void InputMatr(float **, int, int);
```

Буду очень благодарен за помощь в решении проблемы.
Извиняюсь за длинный пост.

Comment: для начала уберите слово `static` из хедеров. Оно в данном случае значит совсем другое.

Comment: без статик сразу 4 ошибки, т.к переменные повторяются и в lab1.cpp и в lab2.cpp

Comment: Вы должны

1. Объявить ваши глобальные переменные в одном и только в одном `.cpp`-файле, так как выделение памяти под переменные происходит только в `.cpp` (примите это без объяснений, объяснять долго)
2. В header'е задекларируйте их как `extern`.
3. Подключите этот header там, где эти переменные нужны. Если получаются циклические зависимости, выделите для данных отдельный header и отдельный .cpp

Ещё лучшей идеей было бы отказаться от глобальных переменных вовсе, но вы же поленитесь провести рефакторинг?

Comment: логично. static делает переменные видимые только внутри объявленного модуля. Вынесите все эти переменные в с++ файл, а в хедерах оставьте `extert int m` и тому подобное.